# Docker-compose is not exposing/mapping the ports, however docker run works ok

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I have an ASP.NET Core app. It's being built for a **Linux** container, although I am developing on **Windows** 10. Docker is running in Linux Containers mode.

When I run `docker run -it --rm -p 5000:80 testh2 instance`, everything works OK and **I can access my web website** on my development machine by going to http://localhost:5000.

However, when I try to run it from by `docker-compose up` command, it does not work - the container starts up OK, but the **website is not available** (`localhost unexpectedly closed the connection.`).

The docker-compose looks as follows:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  hyena.webapp:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}testh2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Hyena.WebApp/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
```

The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base_image
WORKDIR /appDir
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build_step
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Hyena.WebApp/Hyena.WebApp.csproj", "Hyena.WebApp/"]
COPY ["Hyena.Jobs.Contract/Hyena.Jobs.Contract.csproj", "Hyena.Jobs.Contract/"]
   
RUN dotnet restore "Hyena.WebApp/Hyena.WebApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Hyena.WebApp"
RUN dotnet build "Hyena.WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /appDir/build

FROM build_step AS publish_step
RUN dotnet publish "Hyena.WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /appDir/publish

FROM base_image AS final_step 
WORKDIR /appDir
COPY --from=publish_step /appDir/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Hyena.WebApp.dll"]
```

The `testh2` image is something that I built manually by executing `docker build . -t testh2 -f Hyena.WebApp/Dockerfile` from the folder where docker-compose.yml is (repository root).

I thought specifying the ports directive in docker-compose is equivalent to passing it as a parameter to the run command?

What am I doing wrong?

=============================================
**UPDATE**

When I tried mapping the port 5000 to 443, and browsing to https://localhost:5000, it started to work.
No idea why does docker-compose enforce HTTPS, but it seems to be the case.
Not posting this as an answer to my question, as I don't actually know *why*.

=============================================
**UPDATE 2**

Another peculiar thing about this is that it only works when I run the `docker-compose up` from the command line. If I use Visual Studio 'run' option, it does not work - the container seems to be running fine, but the app is not available in the browser.

[image]

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

You're assumption is correct `--publish=5000:80` translates to the `ports` mapping in Docker Compose.

Your `image` value in `hyena.webapp` looks a little wonky. You have the environment variable value plus a hyphen: `${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}` but you likely want `${DOCKER_REGISTRY}` and, if its value is `https://docker.io/`, then you'll probably need your userid and the image, i.e. [https://docker.io/${USERNAME}/testh2`](https://docker.io/$%7BUSERNAME%7D/testh2%60)

But, you need not build the image in Docker Compose if you have already built it locally; using the same image from `docker run` and `docker-compose up` will eliminate the build step.

Please try:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  hyena.webapp:
    image: testh2
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
```

Does that work?

If it does, then you can include the `build` step too:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  hyena.webapp:
    image: testh2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Hyena.WebApp/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
```

> **NOTE** `https://docker.io` is assumed as the registry so you can omit it

Comment: However, it is probably something related to SSL - when I mapped  the ports 5000:443 it worked, with my original docker-compose.
Not sure why compose enforces https.

Comment: and btw, the syntax `${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}` comes from the file generated by visual studio

Comment: I just tried appending a hyphen to an environment variable name and am able to get the value. That's curious behavior but a red-herring here. Is your `testh2` on DockerHub? Is it available publicly? If so, I'd like to try running it.